# Where and how to clean the vendor folder?

Tags: magento2

Where and how to clean the vendor folder?

"If something is corrupt in your composer and you do composer install/update it won't fix it. You have to force reinstall that package. Try cleaning the vendor folder and run composer install or composer update"

Answer (score 8):

The vendor folder is inside your working directory:

[image]

You can remove it with command line:

```
rm -rf vendor/*
```

After that run composer:

```
composer update
```

Comment: Any help with relavant error https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/319343/57334 @Stijn Duynslaeger - Echron thanks

Answer (score 0):

If "composer update" doesn't work, then may want to try execute Install after rm command.
Like this:

```
rm -rf vendor/*
```

After than run composer:

```
composer install
```

That will install/download the vendor directory content.

If your composer command not finished but killed, then can try to increase the memory_limit in the php.ini file. So will allow it use more memory for the composer process.

Can check the current memory_limit from your SSH console:

```
php -i | grep memory
```

Hope that would help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a short shell script that does the job for me. It checks if you are in the correct directory, where the `composer.json` is inside.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! -f "./composer.json" ]
then
    echo "File ./composer.json does not exists"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -d "./vendor" ]
then
    echo "Directory ./vendor does not exists"
fi

# First call without --quiet to get the output of what exactly was changed
composer install "$@";

rm -rf ./vendor;

# Second call after deleting vendor folder to reinstall everything but with --quiet to not push out the previous output
composer install "$@" --quiet;
```

It works also with parameters, e.g.:

```
composer-reinstall -vvv
```