# Magento 2.3 migration error : After migration missing most of the files from vendor/magento/ folder

Tags: migration, magento2.3.4, vendor

Most of the files missing after migration, how to update vendor/magento folder.

[image]

Note : How to update without reinstall fresh Magento

Comment: Please refer to this [link](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Magento-2-3-After-migration-missing-most-of-the-files-from/td-p/455286).

Comment: Are you looking for Migration or upgrade?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I did migration successfully. not upgrade.

Comment: @zus I just saw your message on another ticket, is this still an issue?

Comment: Yes, not able to update missing folders

Answer (score 2):

This question was resolved in the Magento Slack community.

The issue was that they're using the actual Magento release's `composer.json` file, rather than their own `composer.json` that requires Magento itself.

Comment: How to update my composer.json?

Comment: You should follow the Magento documentation for installing via composer: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/composer.html

Answer (score 0):

First of you backup your website and Try this solution :-

If Successful migration try this.

To upgrade to Magento 2.3.x, you need to follow some more steps.

Here's the step-by-step guide to upgrade Magento to 2.3.x:

**`Enable maintenance mode`**

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
```

**`Specify Magento packages`**

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.5 --no-update
```

**`Specify additional packages`**

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit:~6.2.0 friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.10.1 lusitanian/oauth:~0.8.10 pdepend/pdepend:2.5.2 sebastian/phpcpd:~3.0.0 squizlabs/php_codesniffer:3.2.2 --no-update
```

**`Remove unused packages`**

```
composer remove --dev sjparkinson/static-review fabpot/php-cs-fixer --no-update
```

**`Update autoload`**

Open `composer.json` and edit the `"autoload": "psr-4"` section to include `"Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"`:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
        "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
    },
    ...
}
```

**`Apply updates`**

```
composer update
```

**`Clean the Magento cache`**

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

**`Manually clear caches and generated content`**

Clear the `var` and `generated` subdirectories:

```
rm -rf <Magento install dir>/var/cache/*
rm -rf <Magento install dir>/var/page_cache/*
rm -rf <Magento install dir>/generated/code/*
```

**`Update the database schema and data`**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

**`Disable maintenance mode`**

```
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

**`Finally, check your Magento version`**

```
php bin/magento --version
```

And Read More :-

**https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html**

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative solution that I have used and it did resolve my issues at the time.

After following Magento recommendations like most of us do, I still had troubles.
I did install a fresh install of Magento 2.3.x. Then, once the latter was running fine,

- first thing first, I enabled developer mode: `php bin/magento deplo:mode:set developer`
- I did modify composer and add in this working composer file the modules that were used in my site. Then `composer install` needs to run to deploy these modules. At this point, you may have to change the version to comply to the Magento 2.3.x version.

--> if a module version is not working with 2.3.x, you may run `composer require <module-name>`. Once this step is complete, you are over the worse.

- I did deploy my modules from `app/code` folder into this new fresh installed site.
- I did deploy the theme file from `app/design`

then, run `php bin/magento set:up`g. At this point, you may have some issues with your `app/code` modules if your php version has changed. These issues usually are functions signatures to adjust to match the vendor core modules new code. Although it can be daunting, it is usually straightforward at this point